# Is there a way to set my windows to a certain configuration and then swap between configurations with a shortcut?

Tags: workflow, development-environment

While doing web development, I have a few modes that I work in, and each mode has an optimal arrangement of my windows. For example, when coding, I like to have my windows arranged one way (Visual Studio full screen, etc) and when testing in the browser, I like to have my windows totally different (browser, inspect window, source code window etc). I can't simply `Alt` + `Tab` between windows because I am working with multiple windows in each mode.

Is there some way to have a keyboard shortcut that arranges all my windows into configuration A, then another keyboard shortcut that arranges all my windows back to configuration B?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. The best solution I got was to optimize the browser windows myself and save them in local storage for later use.
I used Google Chrome extension for this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-layout-manager/ijpiffheldgmdkbaohoilabdnmeinand?hl=en
I had to use web sockets for communication between browser windows and tabs.